# AzureDevOps commandline as administrator

Tags: azure-devops, windows-services, topshelf

I would like to stop Topshelf service using cmd task in azure devops release pipeline.
What I do is create CommandLineTask which following script:

ServiceName.exe stop

As an output I see

> v3.1.4 2020-06-05T10:14:20.1312163Z The ServiceName service can only
>   be stopped by an administrator

My question is if there is a way to run this CommandLineTask as an administrator?

PS. I use agent on my virtual machine where the service exist itself

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the self-hosted agent, you could try to use the **administrator account** (Local system admin) to create and run the agent.

For interactive mode self-hosted agent:

You could use the following command to create an agent with admin account.

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsAutoLogon --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminaccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```

For service mode self-hosted agent:

On one hand, you could create an agent with the admin account(similar as interactive mode).

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```

On the other hand, you could navigate to **local system -> Service** and find the running agent service.

Then you could change the `logon account` as admin account.

[image: agent]

Here is a doc about  [create agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode).

Comment: Thanks a lot, last point worked for me i.e  change Log On with .\Admininstrator