# Unable to save output from Rscripts in system directory using Devops Pipeline

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, rscript, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am running Rscripts on a self hosted Devops agent. My Windows agent is able to access the system's directory where its hosted. Below is the directory structure for my code

Cloud Agent   :  **D:/folder**

Source Code   :  **D:/folder/project**

Data _dump    :  **D:/folder/dump/**

Output        :  **D:/folder/project/output_data/**

The agent is using CMD in the devops pipeline to trigger R from the system and use the libraries from the system directory.

**Problem statement:** I am unable to save the output from my Rscript in to the **Output Loca.** directory. It give an error as Probable reason: ***permission denied error*** by pointing to that directory.

**Output File Format:** *file_name.rds*   but same issue happens even for a csv file.

**Command leading to failure:** *saverds(paste0(Output loca.,"/",file_name.rds))*

**Workaround :** However I found a workaround, tried to save the scripts at the **Source Code** directory and then save the same files at the **Output Loca.** directory. This works perfectly fine but costs me 2 extra hours of run time because I have to save all intermediatory files and delete them in the end. Keeping the intermediatory files in memory eats up my RAM.

I have not opened that directory anywhere in the machine. Only open application in my explorer is my browser where the pipeline is running. I spent hours to figure out the reason but no success. Even I checked the system Path to see whether I have mentioned that directory over there and its not present.

When I run the same script directly, on the machine using Rstudio, I do not have any issues with saving the file at any directory.

Spent 2 full days already. Any pointers to figure out the root cause can save me few hours of runtime.

Comment: I tried to set my user-id as an admin on all levels in the Devops Pipeline and still the issue persists. My colleagues tried and they were able to write some set of files directly to the destination but not all files. I was doubting whether my COMMAND PROMPT was triggered as an admin and a search for how to trigger CMD as an admin from Devops lead me to the solution as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** was to set the Azure Pipeline Agent services in Windows to run with Admin Credentials. The agent was not configured as an admin during creation and so after enabling it with my userid which has admin access on the VM, the pipelines were able to save files without any troubles.

Feels great, saved few hours of run time!

I was able to achieve this by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213081/azuredevops-commandline-as-administrator) post.