# Azure CICD for deploying SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, azure-devops, cicd

[image: PowerShell task]I have the reports in Azure Repos, I need to deploy these SSRS reports to target server. I tried using the ADO extension 'Deploy SSRS' but it doesn't work for me. Gives out an error related config file(XML file).
Exception setting "Name": "The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."

Is there any other method to deploy the SSRS reports using ADO.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other method to deploy the SSRS reports using ADO.

There is another extension about Deploying SSRS Reports: [SQL Server Reporting Services Deployment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tobania.SqlReportingServices).

On the other hand, you can also directly use the PowerShell script to deploy the SSRS report.

Here is the PowerShell Example, you can refer to it. Example: [Deploy SSRS Reports.ps1](https://gist.github.com/EitanBlumin/e3b34d4c2de793054854e0e3d43f4349)

Comment: Thanks,If I go with the Powershell script, I just need keep this along with the reports in the Azure repo and add the task to copy these files to stagging directory and a release task(Powershell) to run the powershell script by giving its path in Azure repos?

Comment: Yes. you are right. In addition, if you want to deploy to  local server, I suggest you can use self-hosted agent

Comment: Yes tried this, we are using the self hosted agents on a on prem server. The reports  are to be deployed to a report server. I added a power shell task in release pipeline, I gave the path of the power shell script and argument as Run poweshellscript.ps1.

Comment: @Pooja. Can you deploy the report  successfully?

Comment: No I am getting this errorInstall-Module : Administrator rights are required to install modules in 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'. Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install 'C:\Windo2021-09-15T06:02:49.7598591Z ws\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' by 
adding "-Scope CurrentUser" to your command. You can also try running theWindows PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).

Comment: You need to run the agent with the admin account.  you may refer to this ticket:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213081/azuredevops-commandline-as-administrator

Comment: Invalid file path 'E:\Azure_DevOps\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.181.2\_work_ten\r7\a\_Construction-CI (1)\drop1\demo.ps1'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.---tried running from admin account and this is the error getting now

Comment: It seems that the file path is not valid. You need to make sure that you have input the valid path

Comment: Actually I have kept the PowerShell script in  the Azure Repos and copying it to the stagging directory using copy files task in the build pipeline and in the release pipeline in the PowerShell task I have selected the powershell script from the stagging directory