# Can't run docker compose in powershell script on Windows agent in Azure Pipeline

Tags: docker, powershell, azure-pipelines

My script:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
docker compose up
```

I get:

```
##[error]error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-hash%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddmdinference%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.
```

I launched docker desktop from my user account. Pipeline is working from system account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it indicates that the system account have no access to the path **//./pipe/docker_engine** to start the docker daemon.

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following two methods:

1.You can grant the permission to the system account which pipeline is using to access the path: **//./pipe/docker_engine**

PowerShell sample:

```
$account="<DOMAIN>\<USERNAME>"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"                                                                                 
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe                                               
$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()                                                                                 
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl                                       
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow                                                  
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)                                                                                        
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
```

Or you can use the [dockeraccesshelper Powershell Module](https://github.com/tfenster/dockeraccesshelper) to grant the access.

2.You can change to use the user account to run the Pipeline Agent.

For more detailed steps, you can refer to [my ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213081/azuredevops-commandline-as-administrator/62254338#62254338).

Comment: I would like to run only compose up command. Can I run it using some task that doesn't require what you answered?

Comment: As far as I know, the tasks in Azure DevOps can not be able to change the permission of the path to solve the issue.(Because the Pipeline agent uses a service account, it has insufficient permissions.) This issue is related to the permissions of the local machine environment. If the service account cannot access the path //./pipe/docker_engine, Pipeline will not be able to run docker-related operations. So I think that the steps are required to do on your local machine with your user account